# How to consume a google sheet using google api that has a domain restriction

Tags: java, google-sheets, google-api

Well, I would like to know if there is any way to consume a google document that is restricted to the domain of my company, I do not want to leave the document public and as I had to use a google service account to not need the human factor when authenticating the credentials and of course, that email generated does not have the domain of my company, thanks

Comment: I don't understand what you want to accomplish. Could you clarify that? Do you mean you want the document to be only accessible to your domain, but at the same time use a service account? In this case, would [domain-wide delegation](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account#delegatingauthority) be appropriate for you?

Comment: Yes, exactly, that's what I wanted, apreciated

Comment: Since comments are not widely read, I posted an answer which can help others in your same situation. I hope this is helpful to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You want a document to be only accessible to users in your domain.
- You want to use a service account to access that document, in order to avoid user interaction.

In this case, I'd say you have two options at your disposal:

1. [Share the document](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2494822) with your service account, without making the document public. You can have a document shared with all users from your domain and also with the service account (just need to add the service account's email address under `Share with people and groups`).
2. Grant the service account domain-wide authority, so that it can access documents on behalf of any user in the domain, following [these steps](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account#delegatingauthority). Please notice that, in order to do that, you'll need to be an administrator of your domain, and you'll also need to specify which user will the service account act on behalf of.